# How to isolate a substring in a parameter to an m4 macro

Tags: m4

Isolating the first character of a parameter in m4 (standard Unix utility) can be done with

```
define(`firstletter',substr(parameter, 0, 1 ))
```

This makes no sense unless parameter is itself defined. Indeed this example occurs, in a body for a definition, so parameter cannot be quoted.
Unfortunately the parameter can contain the characters, `,' and` )' but not in the first position. Whatever I try, this leads to error messages as the define sees as its firstparameter `substr(C' for the case that parameter contains` C,'.
How can I handle this? With other words fix the above definition for the special cases I mentionned.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have to isolate the first character of the the second parameter $2 in a macro main

```
define(`main', `the first letter is substr($2,0,1)')

main(aap, `a,b')
```

Thus doesnot work because of the comma.

instead define

```
define(`main', `
define({newdef},translit({{$2}},{,()#},{____}))dnl
the first letter is substr(newdef,0,1)')
```

Unless the offending character is in the first position, this kills all the troublesome characters in the remainder of the parameter.
So, this is not an ideal solution.